# Получение данных об использовании телефона, Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-sdk

В Android-приложении мне необходимо получать данные о том, сколько времени был включен телефон, какие программы использовались, соответственно, сколько времени и т.п. Есть ли какие-то способы это сделать, если да, то какие? Информации по этому поводу в интернете не нашёл. Может быть, плохо искал. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сбора статистики приложений - [`android.app.usage.UsageStats`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats) и [`android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager)

Для аптайма телефона - `android.os.SystemClock`, а конкретно метод [uptimeMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis())

Comment: Изучу. Спасибо!